# Calling one handler from another

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am building an eclipse plugin that has handlers (extensions of AbstractHandler) to deal with selecting items from a menu. I have one menu item and handler that creates 'new users' and another set to 'change users'. I would like to have the 'change user' handler be called from the 'new user' handler since it is likely that one would create a new user and change to that user.

Can I call one handler from another? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute the `command` which the handler implements using the handler service.

Get the handler service, in a handler you could use

```
IWorkbenchPart part = HandlerUtil.getActivePartChecked(event);

IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService)part.getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
```

and call the command

```
service.executeCommand("command id", null);
```